# errno 5 during the installation of Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu

I always obtain the errno 5 at approximately 25% of the copying when I install Xubuntu on my P4 2800. I've tried to install on each of my two Samsung spinpoint N, IBM HLAT hard drives. I also tried install through the run on CD. I have verified that all the disks and memory report no errors.

Could you help me?

Comment: Your computer is old since it has a Pentium 4 processor. Your computer should have at least 512MB of RAM to install Xubuntu or at least 128MB RAM to install Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time when a DVD/USB burnt from an [official release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) doesn't work, is because of a bad download.

Therefore type the following command:

```
apt-get install coreutils
md5sum kubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

(above an example for Kubuntu, your exact `.iso` file name will differ) and you will get a number back like this: `a48e3fc0c36a735b2c77e430d985e1e0`

Compare that to the [official Ubuntu hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) and if it's different (you'll see it immediately, that's why I provided a failed hash above) just download it again...

If the md5sum checks out correctly, your CD/DVD disk is damaged.  Burn it again!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this has been solved. But i managed to get xubuntu 14.04 running on my machine after many failed attempts with the errno 5. I was using an iso downloaded from the torrent on xubuntu's main website.

What worked for me:

1. Booted the xubuntu bootable usb previously created.
2. Clicked on try xubuntu.
3. Downloaded "unetbootin".
4. Had "unetbootin" download the "xubuntu 14.04 live" iso image followed by it being installed onto a second usb drive.
5. Restarted pc, booted from usb.
6. Navigated to "install xubuntu" with the arrows keys.
7. Clicked "install xubuntu".
8. Filled in the boxes on the installer.
9. Stared while biting my nails down to the bone........
10. Restarted pc when installer was finished.
11. Waited.... And voila, xubuntu 14.04!!!

Hope this helps someone as much as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot an Xubuntu live-CD
2. Select try Xubuntu without install
3. Open terminal and enter `ubiquity --no-migration-assistant`
4. Open install

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please explain in a little more detail what these steps achieve?